# changing password with authlogic - validation not catching blank inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, authlogic

I am trying to create a form to allow users to change their password:

**View:**

```
- form_tag change_password_users_path do

  = error_messages_for :user, :header_message => "Please Try Again", :message => "We had some problems updating your account" 
  %br

  = label_tag :password, "New password:"
  = password_field_tag "password"
  %br

  = label_tag :password_confirmation, "NConfirm new password:"
  = password_field_tag "password_confirmation"
  %br

  = submit_tag "Update Account"
```

**Controller:**

```
def change_password
  @user = current_user
  if request.post?
    @user.password = params[:password]
    @user.password_confirmation = params[:password_confirmation]
    if @user.save
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      render :action => "change_password"
    end        
  end
end
```

Authlogic is catching validation errors when the password is 'too short' or the password doesn't match the confirmation, but doesn't do anything when the form is submitted with both fields blank.
@user.save must be returning true, because I am redirected to 'user_path(current_user)'.

The password is not actually changed in the database.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just a thought, can you open up the debugger under 'if @user.save' and try to save the record manually, then use @user.changes ?

Comment: The command would be "ruby script/server --debugger"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you call **@user.changed?** like the following example to check for blank passwords:

```
def change_password
  @user = current_user
  if request.post?
    @user.password = params[:user][:password]
    @user.password_confirmation = params[:user][:password_confirmation]
    if @user.changed? && @user.save
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      render :action => "change_password"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should also provide the params[:user][:current_password], otherwise you can not save the @user. And when I tested, I found the current_user will be lost after changing password, so you need update usersession.

Add a 'current_password' accessor to your user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base   
  act_as_authentic   
  attr_accessor :current_password 
end
```

In the user controller

```
def change_password
  @user = current_user
  if @user.valid_password? params[:user][:current_password]
    @user.password = params[:user][:password]
    @user.password_confirmation = params[:user][:password_confirmation]
    if @user.changed? && @user.save
      UserSession.create(:login => @user.login, :password => params[:user][:password])
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      render :action => "change_password"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'current_password=' for #<User:0x000000063ab488>`. Is there some other place you are adding this attribute?

Comment: You will need to add 'attr_accessor :current_password' to your user model.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is the intended behavior.

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/198836

At least I know now...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to exploit ActiveModel validation contexts. You will need to add a context-dependent validation to your User model:

```
validates :password, # :password_confirmation,
          :presence => {:message => 'Please enter your new password.'},
          :on => :reset_password
```

Then, in the controller it will be just:

```
def change_password
  @user = current_user
  if request.post?
    @user.password = params[:password]
    @user.password_confirmation = params[:password_confirmation]
    if @user.save(:context => :reset_password)
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      render :action => "change_password"
    end        
  end
end
```

Hope it will suite ones who were not satisfied with other suggested solutions.